# Websphere 8.5.5 does not resolve / bind to java:module java:global or java:app

Tags: jndi, websphere-8

I have a simple EAR packaged application and several Session beans. There resources that need to get a references so I have an old school service locator for them. It seems that WebSphere 8.5.5 does not make us of the java:module and java:app portable jndi bindings according to the spec.
So.

```
InitialContext c = new InitialContext();
//works - but it is Websphere specific
c.lookup("ejblocal:com.MyService"); 

//Update to original post WORKS - 
c.lookup("java:global/myAppEar/myModuleJar/MyServiceImpl!com.MyService");  
//DOES NOT WORK
c.lookup("java:module/MyServiceImpl!com.MyService"); 
//DOES NOT WORK
c.lookup("java:module/MyServiceImpl"); 


MyService  (plain java interface)

@Local(MyService.class)
MyServiceImpl implements MyService
```

Any ideas or hint? in the server logs I can see that the server is reporting that is binding the ejbs either on its ejblocal space or in java:global . I could find a related bug on Websphere 8.0 but I suppose according to their documentation, it is resolved in version 8.5.5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.base.doc%2Fae%2Fcejb_bindingsejbfp.html ?

Comment: Hi, yes I have gone through this particular documentation. It clear enough, the problem is that when I acquire the InitialContext, every attempt I make to get a look using java:global or similar standard convetions fail with a NamingException. The class that I am performing the lookup is a non managed Bean (an old school Service Locator). When I additionally list() entries on the initial context I resolve to a list of different name spaces , like ejb,etc,jdbc, most probably it is the root JNDI list! Still have not found a solution. Maybe my init of the InitialContext, is not right?

Comment: Still having problems :( https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=c80f4fda-8c7d-44f2-b0cd-a9a8229c8b58

Comment: Eventually we managed to discover that WAS 8.5 is using the java:global namespace correctly, the module and package namespaces are not used (our code was trying to locate with java:module ) etc.

Comment: Same problem here with WAS 8.5.2 and EJB 3.1